# Как правильно построить предложения в рассказе?

Tags: синтаксис

Я не пью (*бухаю*) запоями, - бухаю (*выпиваю или пью*) постоянно... Рюмка обыденно ждет на столе.

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае "пью" или "впадаю в запой", "бухать запоем" выглядит как плеоназм. Во втором случае подойдёт любое слово. Я бы составил фразу немножко по другому.  Как-то так:

*Пью я - не запоями. Я бухаю - постоянно. Рюмочка всегда ждёт меня на столе.*

Этот вариант, как мне кажется, лучше подчёркивает смысл фразы. Небольшая инверсия в первом предложении, вкупе с одинаковой грамматической структурой со вторым, подчёркивают иронию про "незапойность. "Рюмочка" вместо "рюмка" показывает отношение говорящего к этому предмету. Но это всё дело вкуса.

Однако, с точки зрения грамматики предложение правильно (я бы даже сказал, слишком правильное) и сейчас, независимо от того какие слова из скобок использовать.

Answer (score 0):

"Пью" и "запой" - однокоренные слова, их нежелательно употреблять в одном предложении. Лучше подобрать другие варианты. "Бухать" - жаргонизм, если в стиль вашего рассказа допускает подобные слова, то можно оставить. Хотя мне кажется, что "пить запоем" и "бухать" очень близки в значении.
     Ваше предложение я написала бы так: "У меня не бывает запоев, но к рюмочке прикладываюсь постоянно... Она обыденно ждет меня на столе."
  Можно использовать: "пропустить рюмочку, другую", " заложить за воротник" и др

Answer (score 0):

Если Я-рассказчик противопоставляет два образа пьянства, предпочитая, разумеется, свой, стоит, наверное, подчеркнуть это противопоставление лексически: "Я запоем не бухаю - выпиваю (понемногу? по чуть-чуть?) постоянно... Рюмка обыденно стоит на столе."
Просторечное "бухаю"  рядом со смягчённым "выпиваю" получает пренебрежительный оттенок.